# Display Git commit content as a tree in console

Tags: git, tree

Is there a way to display the whole repository content as a tree for a specific commit using the `git` command?

Just display what `git clone` would mount for a concrete repository stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git ls-tree --full-tree --name-only -r HEAD` lists the files in a commit (in this case `HEAD`, but can any commit).